# How to dynamically show/hide a facebook login button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

How can I determine via javascript if a user has logged in to my site via
facebook connect or not? Based on this result, I would like to show/not show a `<fb:login-button>`
button on the site.

If I did something like this using jquery:

```
<div id="login"></div>

<script>
if (notLoggedIn)
{
   $("#login").html("<fb:login-button></fb>");
}
</script>
```

Will it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did It this way:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="logindisplay">
    <span id="login">
      <fb:login-button background="dark" onlogin="facebook_onlogin_ready();">
      </fb:login-button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function updateUserBox() {
    var user_box = document.getElementById("login");
    user_box.innerHTML = "<span><fb:name uid=loggedinuser useyou='false'></fb:name><fb:profile-pic uid=loggedinuser facebook-logo='true'></fb:profile-pic></span>";
    FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree();
        } 

FB_RequireFeatures(["Connect"], function() {
            FB.init("appkey", "/Content/xd_receiver.htm", { "ifUserConnected": updateUserBox });
            FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("publish_stream,status_update");
            FB.Connect.requireSession();
        });
```

Comment: Have you noticed that when you refresh the page, the original Login button shows up, then it switches to your profile picture?  How do you avoid having this happen?

Comment: @JackMarchetti this is happening to me. How did you solve ? Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira I don't recall actually. The FB API has changed a lot over the last 8 years - including getting rid of FBML.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think jQuery will stop you from inserting non-standard HTML tags, but you'll definitely want to change your closing tag from `</fb>` to `</fb:login-button>`.

Beyond that, whenever you insert XFBML tags into your DOM after page load, you'll need to request that the FB API re-parses the DOM.  This should do just that:

```
FB.ensureInit(function(){
  FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree();
});
```

Comment: The new method is: FB.XFBML.parse();

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use jQuery in facebook. They have their [own a wrapper](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS) for js code. Check also [this](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JavaScript_Client_Library).

Comment: I'm using jquery on my own site/domain name which is using 
facebook connect, not as an actual application on facebook. Do
you think jquery will work for that?

Comment: You can use all the javascript you like if you deploy your Facebook app as an iframe